# Retrieving state from React Router v6 Navigate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to pass state data after navigating to a new route and typescript is telling me

> Property 'email' does not exist on type 'State'."

Parent functional component:

`navigate('/check-mail', { state: { email: "hello, I'm an email" } });`

Child functional Component:

```
const SentPasswordResetInstructions = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    let { email } = location.state;
}
```

I've tried creating an interface like so:
`interface propState { email : string }`

and then using

```
useLocation<propState>();
```

However that throws additional errors. How do I fix this ??

Answer (score 12):

Just solved it! Creating the interface:

```
interface propState {
    email: string;
}
```

And then using

```
let { email } = location.state as propState;
```

Worked!

Comment: Be aware that this will throw an error if you navigate directly to this route, because the state will be null. There's a reason you cannot normally type it on your own.

Answer (score 3):

`useLocation().state` is undefined by default, such as when you navigate directly to this route. Because of this, destructuring properties from it can throw an error because you'll essentially be doing

```
const { email } = undefined;
```

I recommend using some form of type guard or validator (such as [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod)) for the state, so that you can handle situations where it might not contain any data.

```
type MyState = { email: string }

function isStateValid(state: any): state is MyState {
  if (!state) return false; // Makes sure it's not null
  if (typeof state !== "object") return false;
  if (typeof state.email !== "string") return false;
  return true;
}
```

```
const { state } = useLocation(); // state is any or unknown
if (isStateValid(state)) {
  const { email } = state; // state is MyState here
}
```